# Cmus needs output_plugin reset when speakers are plugged in?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, music, cmus

I've installed cmus (http://cmus.sourceforge.net/) both via the source code and dependencies, compiled myself, and via Homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) standard install (it installs all the dependencies as well). Both versions have had the same problem: whenever anything is plugged into the output jack (say, as I'm switching from headphones to speakers), the music stops. cmus is still playing, but no sound comes out until I "set output_plugin:ao" manually again. Annoying. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

According to the cmus man page, `~/.cmus/rc` is where you want to put your own options, as it's read immediately after `~/.cmus/autosave`.

To append the option:

```
$ echo "set output_plugin=ao" >> ~/.cmus/rc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but it helped solve my problem.

In my case I have soundflower installed. I incidentally got some sound in my headphones by a combination of plug/unplug, however the sound level was not adjustable, it ignored the system sound settings, except it muted when the system sound was set to mute.

To fix the issue:

1. Go to Sound section in System Preferences.
2. Plug in your headphones. The output in the Sound preferences should be changed.
   If the new selection is any of the Soundflower outputs, select Headphones.
3. In cmus, run 
   :set set output_plugin=ao

Now I can plug/unplug headphones, restart cmus, sound output properly delivered. Hope that helps